# Нейросеть для рисования

Tags: c++, python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Как делаются нейросети для рисования изображений?

Например НС показывают набор картинок, а далее НС сама рисует изображение из своей "памяти" или дополняет рисунок который на нее подается.

Какой тип НС используется для этих целей?

Comment: по-копайте в направлении "распознавание образов", "машинное обучение", "топология сети". также уже можете приступить к сбору данных для обучения, а также найдите в поисковике "создаём простую нейросеть" и там уже определитесь

Comment: По поводу преобразования рисунков советую посмотреть в сторону [Neural Style Transfer](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=neural+style+transfer). Рисовать с нуля (на чистом листе) - это, по-моему, гораздо сложнее.

Answer (score 7):

На Coursera есть [отличный курс от проф. Andrew Ng - "Convolutional Neural Networks", один из пяти курсов по специализации "Deep Learning"](https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks/home/week/4) и в этом курсе на 4-й неделе в качестве практического задания надо реализовать НС, которая обучается стилю по одной картинке и применяет этот стиль к другой картинке.

[Вот пример решения на Python + TensorFlow](https://github.com/CtheSky/Coursera-Deep-Learning-Specialization/blob/master/Convolutional%20Neural%20Networks/Art%20Generation%20with%20Neural%20Style%20Transfer%20-%20v2.ipynb)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[другие варианты решения той же задачи...](https://www.google.com/search?q=github+Deep+Learning+%26+Art%3A+Neural+Style+Transfer&oq=github+Deep+Learning+%26+Art%3A+Neural+Style+Transfer)